# My login program keeps running when it should not when converted it to a class-based program. How to fix it?

Tags: python

I made a begginer exercise program, a login-system (the code below is just a simple reproductory version). It was first made only with functions (no classes). When I tried to convert it to a class, it keeps running, but it should stop. What's the problem:

```
class LoginSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):
        print("(1) LOGIN")
        print("(2) REGISTER")
        answer = input(">>> ")
        if answer == '1':
            self.login()

    def login(self):
        name = input("Write your username: ")
        if self.user_exists(name):
            passwd = input("Write the password: ")
            print("\nYou are now logged in!")
            print("\nPassword is incorrect.")
        else:
            print("\nUser doesn't exist.")

    def user_exists(self, username):
        with open('login_info.txt', 'r') as rf:
            for line in rf:
                user = line.strip().lower().split(" ")[0]
                if user == username:
                    return True
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = LoginSystem()
    a.main_menu()
```

The login() is a simple version, it is more complex in reality. When I run the program and enter the login section, then input a inexistent username in the login_system.txt file, the program shows `User doesn't exist.` as it should, but then the menu screen is printed again? Why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an instance of a class, the `__init__()` function runs automatically.  Your `__init__()` function calls `self.main_menu()`.

Then you explicitly call `a.main_menu()` again.

Either remove the `main_menu()` call from `__init__()` (in which case you wouldn't need `__init__()` at all), or don't call `a.main_menu()`.

Comment: Thanks,  I forgot that __init__() is called automatically!

Answer (score 2):

When `a = LoginSystem()` is run, the `__init()__` method is started. In it, you run `self.main_menu()`.At second, you start main menu with `a.main_menu()`. I think, `a.main_menu()` is not needed.
Hope this would help.